# How to make moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: animation slower/faster

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation

I want to make `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` animation slower/faster ,
 is there some good way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

A best code snippet to animate table view cell i have ever found, just add this function in addition to your tableview code, customize animation according to you

```
//This function is where all the magic happens
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    //1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
    CATransform3D rotation;
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
    rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;


    //2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    cell.alpha = 0;

    cell.layer.transform = rotation;
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);


    //3. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    cell.alpha = 1;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: